# Identify whether or not are devices on the same iCloud programmatically?

Tags: ios, icloud

I have two devices and would like to identify whether or not they are on the same iCloud profile. How can I achieve this programmatically ?

Comment: How are they connected to each other?

Comment: Only via icloud

Answer (score 1):

You can use an iCloud container and write a file into it with any information you want to share between the devices. To access the same folder from both devices they must be logged in with the same account.

CloudKit documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit

> You use CloudKit to take your app’s existing data and store it in the cloud so that the user can access it on multiple devices.